# How to use GRASS v.buffer function in QGIS?

Tags: grass-gis, buffer

[image]

[image]

[image]
Trying to use the v.buffer function to create a 500-foot buffer (map units are in metres, which is why I put 152.4 meters as the buffer distance) around the boundary of a property parcel (not the centroid). I'm unsure what to populate the "'Category values' and 'WHERE conditions of SQL statement without 'where' keyboard'. All I want to do is create a 500-foot buffer around the parcel boundary, so I am finding a lot of these fields don't apply to me. When I try to run what I have entered, I get the error that there are not enough arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the **WHERE** conditions should not apply to your case, but unfortunately we cannot escape from this keyword - it is mandatory as far as I know.

I usually set a dummy (meaningless) condition, such as **"ID" > 0** or **"ELEVATION" < 1000000** so that the conditions always return TRUE.

[Example] - [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) dataset

Ir has a `"scalerank"` field which is always `1`, so I can set `"scalerank" > 0` into the `where` condition.

[image]

Then **v.buffer** runs smoothly and returns output like below:

[image]

Many GRASS vector commands demand this WHERE clause - but I honestly do not know why.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. So what do you enter for the category values then?

Comment: @sophiasmarand I leave the category values blank.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the `where=` parameter is **not** mandatory when running this module in GRASS itself.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks @Micha - Hope this can be fixed in QGIS interface soon.